# Event binding on dynamically added datepicker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I'm using kendo datepicker here, i have an original div with two datepickers and a duplicated div with two datepickers as well, when i duplicate the div the datepicker events fire once only on the first duplicated div then it stops working, i tried event binding but it didn't work, can anybody help here?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".from, .to").kendoDatePicker();

  $('.calendar').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.k-datepicker').find('input').data("kendoDatePicker").open();
  });

  $('.from, .to').each(function(index, el) {
    $(el).bind("focus", function() {
      $(this).data("kendoDatePicker").open();
    });
  });

  $('.duplicate-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var duplicateable = $(this).next('.duplicate');

    var html = $('<div>').append(duplicateable.clone()).html();
    $(html).insertBefore(duplicateable);
    var new_el = duplicateable.next('.duplicate');
    new_el.fadeIn(600).removeClass('duplicate');
  });
});
```

```css
.k-dropdown-wrap .k-select,
.k-numeric-wrap .k-select,
.k-picker-wrap .k-select {
  display: none !important;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.duplicate {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div>
  <label>From</label>
  <input class="from">
  <button class="calendar">Calendar</button>
</div>

<div>
  <label>To</label>
  <input class="to">
  <button class="calendar">Calendar</button>
</div>

<button class="duplicate-btn">Duplicate</button>

<div class="duplicate">
  <div>
    <label>From</label>
    <input class="from">
    <button class="calendar">Calendar</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>To</label>
    <input class="to">
    <button class="calendar">Calendar</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not [`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) those elements. They go with a lot of properties from the widget. Instead I suggest you to use templates to create new elements and then initialize the widgets on them:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $(document).on('focus', '[data-role="datepicker"]', function(index, el) {
          $(this).data("kendoDatePicker").open();
      });
      
      $('input[type="date"]').kendoDatePicker();
      
      $('button').on('click', function() {
        let newDatesTemplate = kendo.template($("#dates-template").html()),
            newDates = newDatesTemplate({}),
            $newDatesDOM = $(newDates);
        
        $newDatesDOM
          .appendTo('#container')
          .find('input')
           .kendoDatePicker();
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script id="dates-template">
    <div>
      <input type="date" class="from">
      <input type="date" class="to">
    </div>
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <input type="date" class="from">
    <input type="date" class="to">
  </div>
  
  <div id="container"></div>
  <button>Add more dates</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Explanation:

- The template:

  ```
  <script id="dates-template">
    <div>
      <input type="date" class="from">
      <input type="date" class="to">
    </div>
  </script>
  ```

  A simple example of the template.
- Adding more elements:

  ```
  let newDatesTemplate = kendo.template($("#dates-template").html()), // Creates the template with the `script#dates-template` content
      newDates = newDatesTemplate({}), // Runs the template
      $newDatesDOM = $(newDates); // Creates a jQuery object with the result

  $newDatesDOM
    .appendTo('#container') // Appends the new DOM elements to a target element
    .find('input')
      .kendoDatePicker(); // Inits the widgets
  ```
- Now this will do the magic you want:

  ```
  $(document).on('focus', '[data-role="datepicker"]', function(index, el) {
      $(this).data("kendoDatePicker").open();
  });
  ```

That event delegation will execute an event in the original elements and in the dynamically added elements because it is bound to the `document`.

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@marcio/ArIJOfAf)

Answer (score -1):

Right off the bat, I can see you're assigning two different divs to the same variable declared twice.

`var datepicker = $(".from").data("kendoDatePicker");
var datepicker = $(".to").data("kendoDatePicker");`

Start off by declaring it separately:

```
var datepicker_from = $(".from").data("kendoDatePicker");
var datepicker_to = $(".to").data("kendoDatePicker");
```

Comment: Is that variable ever actually used?

Comment: After writing it, realize it's not... even then those errors bother me. Good habits breed good results.